# How to bind Dictionary to ListBox in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, data-binding, listbox

It is possible to bind a Dictionary to a Listbox, keeping in sync between the Listbox and the member property?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
var choices = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
choices["A"] = "Arthur"; 
choices["F"] = "Ford"; 
choices["T"] = "Trillian"; 
choices["Z"] = "Zaphod"; 
listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(choices, null); 
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"; 
listBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

(Shamelessly lifted from my own blog: [Bind a ComboBox to a generic Dictionary](http://www.madprops.org/blog/Bind-a-ComboBox-to-a-generic-Dictionary/).)

This means you can use SelectedValue to get hold of the corresponding dictionary key for the selected item in the ListBox.

Comment: Does it actually require a `BindingSource` there?

Comment: Yeah in my experience it needs the BindingSource.

Comment: I've tried this, and it works partially, ie if i do this, after setting datasource for listbox:
            
choices["M"] = "abc";
choices.Remove("T");

the listbox does not reflect the changes in the choices dictionary...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure you'll get it to work if you're modifying the underlying dictionary after the fact. Dictionaries don't notify when they're changed like BindingList<T> or ObservableCollection<T> does.

Comment: Anyone else getting an ArgumentNull exception when creating the new BindingSource(...)??

Comment: You will get a null exception if your Dictionary is empty, you need at least one item.

Comment: @Matt Is it possible to remove items from the list and have them be removed from the dictionary as well?

Comment: @Uriel This answer was nearly four years ago, and it's been at least that long since I did any WinForms. I honestly have no idea. :)

Comment: hello Matt, thanks for the information but I have a problem with the method when removed all elements from one textbox to another , system.collection is added to the textbox which has no items left

Answer (score 1):

```
        label1.Text= listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();

        if ( listBox1.SelectedItem is KeyValuePair<int,DockStyle>)
        {

            var temp1 = (KeyValuePair<int, DockStyle>)listBox1.SelectedItem;
            label3.Text = temp1.Key.ToString();
            label4.Text = temp1.Value.ToString();


        }
```

Comment: I know this is not a matching answer to the question but this helped when I needed to get the selected item after binding

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use events for that. Whenever something changes in ListBox, an eventHandler method will add/remove same thing from Dictionary.