# ListBox toBind Dictionary<string, Object>

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, listbox, bind

Is there a way to Bind Dictionary to a ListBox?
e.g:
I Have this Class:

```
   class Person
    {
        private string _firstName;
        private string _lastName;
        private int _age;

        public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
        {
            this._firstName = firstName;
            this._lastName = lastName;
            this._age = age;
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { this._firstName = value; }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { this._lastName = value; }
        }

        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set { this._age = value; }
        }
    }
```

and I use it as the value of my dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, Person> _persons = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
```

and i want to Bind it to listBox ... but I need to choose what Item to Bind ...
e.g: I want to Bind Person, then all Person only will appear in DisplayMember of listBox ...

i tried this answer:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/854953/datagridview-bound-to-a-dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854953/datagridview-bound-to-a-dictionary) of Chris
but the output displayed on listbox perItem was something like:

```
{ Key = key, Value = ObjectValue }
```

Question: Is there another way to do this? or how to fix this atleast edit the item of listbox?

**Updated:**
I just saw this answer a while ago:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/1506987/how-to-bind-dictionary-to-listbox-in-winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506987/how-to-bind-dictionary-to-listbox-in-winforms)

and it seems working! But my Problem now was How about if I want to Display Data From *Values* ... *what to put on listBox.DisplayMember ?*

Comment: Did you create DataTemplate for you list box itemTempalte, and bind to your property?

Comment: havent try yet @Jamaxack

Comment: it might help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: is it possible onwinforms? @Jamaxack ... (sorry i forgot to tag but now added)

Comment: WinForm does not have DataTempalte, So you can go by setting yourListName.DisplayMemberPath = "Value.FirstName"; If you need i can make Demo Project on WPF or WInForms. @Elegiac

Comment: @scheien, its not duplicate since im using an Object as my value

Comment: @Jamaxack, i already tried: Value.Person ... but it keeps displaying key.[SolutionName].Person ... i also tried Value.FirstName, it displayed correctly ... problem was only the 1st data

Comment: What do you mean by 1st Data and what is the problem? @Elegiac

Comment: if i have greater than 1 data on my list ... e.g: list[0].Value.Firstname = "Stack"; list[1].Value.FirstName = "Overflow"; ... only 'Stack' will display in list

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to specify something like "Person.FirstName" in the `DisplayMember` of a listbox in winforms.

What you could do is override `Person`'s `ToString` method or rather than binding a dictionary you could bind a `List<Person>`...

Or have a class just for binding and the bind `List<CustomPerson>`.

```
public class CustomPerson
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public string DisplayValue
    {
        get { return Person.FirstName; }
    }
}
```

Then set `DisplayMember` to `DisplayValue`.