# How to add data in ListBox?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have Dictionary:

```
 public Dictionary<int, string> jobs = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

It is filled like this:

```
 this.jobs.Add(1, "Усі види підземних робіт, відкриті гірничі роботи.");
```

I tried to add values from jobs Dictionary:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in jobs.get()) {
   listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("№{0} - ({1})", kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString()));
}
```

As you can see I add to list value `"№{0} - ({1})"`. But how to set key?

Comment: what do you mean 'how to set key?'

Comment: I meant to set key/value for item in ListBox, that after click to get key

Comment: and what is `jobs.get` dictionary has not such method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1507008/669576

Comment: another approach, create a cusotm object that contains key (and maybe value ) and ToString method. Add that object to the listbox

Comment: Can you demonstrate example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample of what [pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173397/pm100) has suggested:

Create a model class for binding the list box as follows:

```
class Job
  {
        public int Key { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("№{0} - ({1})", this.Key, this.Description);
        }
  }
```

Next, project a list of `Job` from the dictionary as follows:

```
var jobList = this.jobs
                  .Select(it =>
                                new Job
                                {
                                    Key = it.Key,
                                    Description = it.Value
                                })
                  .ToList();
```

Instead of adding the dictionary items in a for-each loop, bind the data source of the `ListBox` as follows:

```
this.listBox1.DataSource = jobList;
```

And that's about it. The listbox will display each item by invoking the `ToString()` method overridden in the `Job` class.

Now you could access the job object and its key by casting the `SelectedItem` / `SelectedItems` as follows:

```
var job = this.listBox1.SelectedItem as Job;
// job.Key
```