# How to use dictionary in class

Tags: c#

How do i add items to dictionary using a textbox, i am also facing problems on linking my dictionary to a listbox since i created my dictionary in a class, how do i call `alphabet` from class to Form1

***MY CLASS with the dictionary***

```
class MyCipher: ICipherDecipher
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> alphabet;

    public MyCipher()
    {
        alphabet = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        alphabet.Add("4", " take 4");
        alphabet.Add("3", " take 3");
        alphabet.Add("5d", " for 5 days");
    }
}
```

***main code***

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ICipherDecipher myCipher;

    public Form1()
    {
        myCipher = new MyCipher();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string textToBeCiphered = textBox1.Text;
        string textCiphered = myCipher.Cipher(textToBeCiphered, 6);
        textBox2.Text  = textCiphered;
    }
}
```

how do i call the dictionary `alphabet` from my class to main code in Form1 so that i can display it in listbox property??

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: Look here for how to bind the dictionary to the listbox: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1506987/5803406

Comment: And to access your dictionary you'll need to either make `alphabet` public instead of private or add another public property or method that returns `alphabet`

Comment: One wonders why you put the dictionary inside a class if you want to access it dorectly from elsewhere

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do: `string textCiphered = myCipher.Cipher(textToBeCiphered, 6);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change the type of `myCipher` to `MyCipher`**

Change this line:

```
private ICipherDecipher myCipher;
```

To this line:

```
private MyCipher myCipher;
```

**Add a property for the alphabet**

Change this line:

```
    private Dictionary<string, string> alphabet;
```

To this line:

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> alphabet {get; set;}
```

**Then you can bind it to your listbox:**

```
listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(myCipher.alphabet, null);
```

**To Set a ListView based on the Dictionary (2 Columns):**

```
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        listView1.Items.AddRange(myCipher.alphabet.Select(c => new ListViewItem
           (
             new string[] { c.Key, c.Value}
           )).ToArray());
```

**To Set a ListView based on the Dictionary (1 Column):**

```
listView1.Items.AddRange(myCipher.alphabet.Select(c => new ListViewItem(c.Key + " : " + c.Value)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Can you please help with an example using my values

Comment: where exactly should i change `myCipher` to `MyCipher`

Comment: thank you it worked, So i can do the same with list??

Comment: is it possible to show the dictionary on a list view???

Comment: thank you very much, but the listview is just showing the codes only eg `4 3 5d` , its not showing the descriptions

Comment: thank you very much, sorry to bother you is it possible for a user to use two textboxes to enter key and value to the dictionary??

Comment: using the listbox

Answer (score 3):

MyCipher class should be public and alphabet should be property, not field and its access modifier should be protected or public:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Alphabet { get; set; }
```

After that you can access it from other parts of your code like this:

```
var myCipher = new MyCipher();
var myDictionary = myCipher.Alphabet;
```

Comment: how will i then use that code with the `alphabet` i created?

Answer (score 0):

If you want good performance for lookup up on both keys and values, you might consider using a [`SortedList<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netcore-3.1) instead of a `Dictionary`. Check the **Remarks** section in the link to see what the differences are and if it's a better fit.

But aside from that, as others have said, you need to make the dictionary `public` if you want clients of the class to have access to it.

But is that really what you want? It seems to me that if you're writing a class that creates a cipher code, you want methods like `Encipher` (or `Encode`) and `Decipher` (or `Decode`), and a method that lets the client add values to the private dictionary/sorted list.

Yes, **private** dictionary (or sorted list). Because this is the *internal implementation* for your class, but the **public interface** you expose should be more "cypher-like".

For example:

```
public class Cipher
{
    private SortedList<string, string> CodeMappings = new SortedList<string, string>();

    public void AddCode(string codedPhrase, string decodedPhrase)
    {
        CodeMappings[codedPhrase] = decodedPhrase;
    }

    public string Decipher(string codedMessage)
    {
        return CodeMappings
            .OrderBy(item => item.Key.Length)
            .Aggregate(codedMessage, (current, codeMapping) =>
                current.Replace(codeMapping.Key, codeMapping.Value));
    }

    public string Encipher(string normalMessage)
    {
        return CodeMappings
            .OrderBy(item => item.Value.Length)
            .Aggregate(normalMessage, (current, codeMapping) =>
                current.Replace(codeMapping.Value, codeMapping.Key));
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var cipher = new Cipher();
cipher.AddCode("4", " take 4");
cipher.AddCode("3", " take 3");
cipher.AddCode("5d", " for 5 days");

var message = "The doctor recommends you take 4 for 5 days.";

// Show the original message
Console.WriteLine("Original message: " + message);

// Show the encoded message
message = cipher.Encipher(message);
Console.WriteLine("Encoded message: " + message);

// Now show the decoded message
Console.WriteLine("Decoded message: " + cipher.Decipher(message));
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: i want to use the dictionary i made in rest of the code